# Equivalent class declaration using C++/CX from WRL declaration

Tags: windows-runtime

I have this WRL declaration (taken from Grayscale filter from samples provided by MS):

```
class CGrayscale: public RuntimeClass<
                             RuntimeClassFlags<WinRtClassicComMix>,
                             IMediaExtension,
                             IMFTransform
                          >
```

How do I convert that class to C++/CX?
The reason I need to do so is because in the same DLL I have classes defined using C++/CX which automatically under the hood generates class factory for these classes (The DllGetActivationFactory export from my dll). That automatic C++/CX class factory declaration conflicts with class factory declaration that I have to do for a runtime class defined by WRL.

So, the easiest way it seems to convert that WRL declaration to C++/CX. If it's impossible to define that class using C++/CX, what can I do to make WRL and C++/CX defined runtime classes to co-exist (e.g. be discoverable) in the same dll?